# The group by operation contains an expression that cannot be translated

Tags: c#, linq

It compiles normal but when I try to iterate through result of the LINQ query I 've got such exception `The group by operation contains an expression that cannot be translated`
The query is

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
              where Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(left) >= 0
              && Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(right) <= 0
              && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
            group c by new { ((DateTime)c.data).Year, ((DateTime)c.data).Month }
                  into groupMonthAvg
                  select new
                  {
                      years = groupMonthAvg.Key.Year,
                      months = groupMonthAvg.Key.Month,
                      prices = groupMonthAvg.Average(i => i.value)
                  };
```

What expression in `group by` function is wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `c.data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
             let date = Convert.ToDateTime(c.data)
             where date.CompareTo(left) >= 0 && date.CompareTo(right) <= 0 && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
             group c by new { date.Year, date.Month } into groupMonthAvg
             select new
             {
                 years = groupMonthAvg.Key.Year,
                 months = groupMonthAvg.Key.Month,
                 prices = groupMonthAvg.Average(i => i.value)
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is because the `data` column in `Price` is a String or some other type other than `DateTime`.

Try changing the `(DateTime)c.data)` cast to a `Convert.ToDateTime(c.data)` instead.

I am not sure if the Linq-SQL translator supports casts.

If possible change the underlying data type in the database to a `DateTime` if it stores a Date Time value.